# Does jQuery not work with id's sent over an Ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it true?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#reset").click(function(){alert("hi");});
    });
</script>

<ul>
    <li id="reset">Reset</li>
</ul>
```

The above code works fine. But if I get the list over an Ajax call it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Are you saying that an ajax call returns the li with id reset? And the click event does not fire?

Comment: There is some other problem in your code. It will perfect.

Comment: @andrew-buchan yeah i mean what you say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the DOM which not be prepared at the onLoad stage you will need to bind using `on`
 as in

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#reset', function() {
   alert("hi");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not true. You need to use the `on` method for dynamically generated content:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#reset' ,function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

With `on` you can use event delegation by registering events on a parent element that is already present in the DOM. Events from an element added dynamically will bubble up to the event you registered with, and the handler will only be called if the actual target of the event matches the selector you passed in.

Comment: You need to explain what the difference is. The only people who will understand it are the people who already know it

Comment: Provided the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

When you create an element dynamically you can't handle them directly, so you have to makes use of `.on()`:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#reset' ,function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

A brief explanation can be:

When you use a normal event registration model, it will register the handlers directly to the targeted which are present in the DOM at the point of the handler registration execution. So elements which are added later dynamically will not get those handlers.

The solution to this is to use event delegation. In this model the handler is registered to an ancestor element which will be present when the page is loaded with the a selector to filter out the source element. This makes use of event propagation - events happening in an element is propagated to all the ancestor elements (there are few exceptions like focus event). So an event happening in an element gets propagated to the ancestor element in one of them the handler is registered then the events source element (event.target) and its ancestors are matched against the selector passed as the second parameter, if it is satisfied then the handler is executed.

http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: This answer is being [discussed on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196559/what-to-do-in-a-such-case-if-it-seems-that-someone-is-missing-to-cite-right). (If you're going to copy and paste without attribution, at least fix the typos.)

Comment: @Wooble yeah i copy the explanation from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708874/why-does-click-without-body-not-work/18708881#18708881) but i answered before him.What should i do if he posted the answer after me with the explanation he made earlier ?

Answer (score 2):

**Event delegation**

When you use a normal event registration model, it will register the handlers directly to the targeted which are present in the DOM at the point of the handler registration execution. So elements which are added later dynamically will not get those handlers.

The solution to this is to use event delegation. In this model the handler is registered to an ancestor element which will be present when the page is loaded with the a selector to filter out the source element. This makes use of event propagation - events happening in an element is propagated to all the ancestor elements (there are few exceptions like focus event). So an event happening in an element gets propagated to the ancestor element in one of them the handler is registered then the events source element (event.target), and its ancestors are matched against the selector passed as the second parameter, if it is satisfied then the handler is executed.

http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

So try

```
$(document).on('click', '#reset', function() {
    // Your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#reset', function() {
   alert("hi");
});
```

The first selector has to be an element that won't be replaced. This way, when the event bubbles up to this point it is caught. You then specify the actual element that will trigger the event as the 2nd parameter of `.on`